# Typo3 (8.731) Plugin Controller ignored the first time, every call after that works fine

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have a typo3 plugin, that handles the `/code/xyz`.

When a code is called the first time it doesn't work and results in a 404. When it's called the second time it's running into the controller (I've set breakpoints there).

What could be the reason for the difference of behavior between the two calls. With nothing changed by me two calls right after each other exhibit the same behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can understand what the problem is, but i can not help you find what is the reason why this happens, because we have no idea how your plugin works, how it is implemented and how it is programmed. Unfortunately this is a very abstract question.

Comment: Update from slack: we tried adding the domain to the Realurl config, that didn't change anything

Comment: removing Realurl made a difference, so I guess it's a faulty configuration there somewhere.

Comment: When encountering problems with realurl, I always truncated all the tx_realurl tables. That would only lose you old redirects, the rest is just cache. Then start by first generating the URL somewhere (that step is important for realurl's SEO-URL->parameter-URL resolving) and then call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this one was a hard one to crack.

Even though we thought is was Realurl the problem was a different one.

The integrator doing the upgrade from 7 to 8 missed one breaking change:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78002-EnforceCHashArgumentForExtbaseActions.html